# python3 string interpolation - two ways, neither one works

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given these 2 different string interpolation stanzas, neither one works. Both return the {n} and %(text) inserts as plain, raw text in the output. What am I missing?

Ive been using the %(string)s method forever in python2, now porting to python 3.

```py
bulk_string = (
    "bulk insert SomeDB.dbo.%(lru)s\n" +
    "from 'C:\\Someplace\\"
    "project\\%(filename)s'\n" +
    "with (\n" +
    "  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',\n" +
    "  ROWTERMINATOR = '%(term)s'\n" +
    ");"
    % {
        'lru': lru,
        'filename': filename,
        'term' : "\n"
    }
)
```

and:

```
bulk_string = (
    "bulk insert SomeDB.dbo.{0}\n" +
    "from 'C:\\Someplace\\"
    "project\\{1}'\n" +
    "with (\n" +
    "  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',\n" +
    "  ROWTERMINATOR = '{2}'\n" +
    ");"
    .format(lru, filename, "\n")
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

either `format` or `%` apply only to the last string of your added strings. You could use `"""` (triple quoted strings) or parenthesize the strings (that, you did, but incorrectly):

```
bulk_string = (
    "bulk insert SomeDB.dbo.{0}\n" +
    "from 'C:\\Someplace\\"
    "project\\{1}'\n" +
    "with (\n" +
    "  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',\n" +
    "  ROWTERMINATOR = '{2}'\n" +
    ");")
    .format(lru, filename, "\\n")
```

or with triple quotes/raw string/automatic format positionning:

```
bulk_string = r"""bulk insert SomeDB.dbo.{}
from 'C:\Someplace\project\{}'
with (
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '{}'
   );""".format(lru, filename, "\\n")
```

Aside: the third parameter of `format` should be `\\n` or r`\n` if you want to generate a literal `\n` in your code.

Comment: In your first stanza above it was the misplaced closing parenthesis that was screwing it up - thanks! I had to go back into my 2.7 code and look but, for the record, my first stanza above (with the %(string)s method) works fine if you omit all the plus signs - then the following % {} interpolation applies to the whole thing...

Comment: note that you can pass a dict to `format` too, and use `{lru}` ... as placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most readable way to do this:

In Python 3, you can use literal string interpolation, or f-strings, see [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) - just be careful with escaping the backslashes properly, especially in front of a curly bracket such as in `C:\Someplace\project\\{filename}`

```
lru = "myTable"
filename = "myFile"
rt = "\\n"
bulk_string = f"""bulk insert SomeDB.dbo.{lru} 
                  from 'C:\Someplace\project\\{filename}'
                  with ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ,
                         ROWTERMINATOR = '{rt}');"""
```

Comment: you still need escaping of the windows paths. It works here, but replace "project" by "table" and you'll see that \t turns to <TAB>. Or use rf prefix